# Ignore Characters in an excluded character range

Tags: regex

I have a regex statement to remove all characters except A-Z and 0-9 (it matches everything else and replaces with a "" with preg_replace)

```
/[^A-Z0-9]/
```

It works well for those characters, but now I'm looking to remove certain characters that look similar to the eye (i.e. 'O' and '0').

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the duplicate answer and playing around with it - you might need to remove the '+' off the end to get it working as you want.

The '+' quantifier won't exclude the characters if they are part of a word.

https://regex101.com/r/83w6Yb/2

With the '+' out, it matches every character in the lookahead list

https://regex101.com/r/83w6Yb/3

Final RegEx = `/(?![oO0])[a-zA-Z0-9]/g`

Hope this helps